# UIImagePickerController with cameraOverlayView - misplaced views

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a `UIImagePickerController` with a custom cameraOverlayView.

I create the imagePicker like this:

```
self.overlay = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OverlayViewController"];
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;

// Insert the overlay
self.picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlay.view;
self.overlay.pickerReference = self.picker;

self.picker.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
self.picker.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;

self.picker.delegate = self.overlay;


[self presentViewController:self.picker animated:NO completion:^{

}];
```

For some reason, the OverlayViewController's view is misplaced. It seems as if the constraints haven't been calculated. However, if I explicitly call `[self.overlay viewWillAppear:NO];` in the completion block, they layout seems to render correctly.

After some investigation it seems as if `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` is not called for the `OverlayViewController`.

However, these methods are called if I come back to the imagePicker from a modal 'custom gallery viewcontroller'.

I.e:
rootVC-> (No calls) -> imagePicker -> customGalleryVc
customGalleryVc (dismiss modal) -> (Calls to willAppear) -> imagePicker

What is this? Am I missing something with the fundamentals of the view-hierarchy?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

View controller lifecycle methods are called only when the view controller is added into the view controller hierarchy.

The first line of the snippet only instantiated the VC. As you access the view property of the VC, its view (you defined in IB) is loaded. That's all, nothing else happened.

So, a suggestion would be that there is no need to use a view controller for your custom overlay. You just need a normal UIView. With IB, you may create the overlay in a xib, or in a storyboard drag a UIView object to the dock (the top bar of a scene where any gesture recogniser appear if you add any) of your current VC, then you can reference them by creating an IBOutlet.

Comment: See the updated question, the lifecycle methods are called when I come back to the imagePicker from another modal view controller.

Comment: @Spoek I guess you presented the gallery VC from a control in your overlay VC. If so, I think the system may add your overlay VC into the VC hierarchy at some point, so when you come back, its lifecycle is called as normal. Anyway, this is not the right way to go. `UIImagePickerController` expects just a standalone UIView as its custom overlay, not a view from somewhere else.